# Is identifying font used in anime or manga on-topic?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

This question asks for the font used in subtitles:

[What's the EXACT Japanese subtitle font used in Evangelion bluray?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/65949/102)

I'm not convinced that this isn't analogous to the other kinds of identification questions about characters out there, but I wanted to see what others thought of this.

Comment: Personally, I have a tendency to make it off-topic, but my current reasonings may not be so convincing. FWIW, our sister site [graphicdesign.se] accepts [font identification](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/30985).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical identification question and should be closed due to lack of information and context, even if it wasn't one. It should be still closed in my opinion due to lack of context.

It lacks critical information on which bluray it's from, particularly its country of origin. There are many different blurays for many different countries for many different versions and cuts of Evangelion.

Depending on how the media is player, different media players may use different (default) fonts, unless the subs were hard-coded (which is unlikely unless it was a rip). Therefore, it might be a user-specific issue and not be answerable without proper content.

If one is asking for exact information, then exact details should be provided. We're not a visual font identification service. Information should flow both ways.

I feel that these types of questions will always be  regarded as being tertiary in regards to the series, its content, its staff, and its productions. A question comparing the ADV subtitles to the Netflix subtitles of original Evangelion would likely be more on-topic than this question.

Just like how we don't identify anime cels (it's an image id-req) or do stuff in regards to music composition (something better left to those more adept to music theory).

If we get questions asking us to find something that does not correspond to content directly (i.e. series/franchise-specific, character-specific, VA-specific, series/character design-specific) or its production (behind-the-scenes details (made-up languages in the series), its staff, history [i.e., extra lore from data books], promotional material, etc) without a given reason or purpose (e.g., I'm trying to find X because of Y): We should be closing these questions without a second thought.

That's not to say all request for information and resources should be off-topic - but if the asker can't provide sufficient context on what or why they are looking for something, we should not be taking the time to fill in their blanks.

Comment: Agreed. My (vague) feeling is that this particular question reads like a "[boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19487#19487)" question. Its relevance towards the anime/manga, or towards its appreciation, is not at all clear.